# why is my program only displaying pieces of a $http request I'm making?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, q

I'm working on a pokedex project , I currently am pulling data from pokeAPI to get information about different pokemon based on the name they type in a search bar. At which point it's supposed to fill up the page with the data of said pokemon. It will bring up all the data for a moment. It will flicker on the screen before disappearing. only a couple pieces end up staying on the screen I'm still very new as node.js so any and all help/suggestions are very welcome!

EDIT: so the way I got it working was simply changing it to have a pokeData and pokeData2 and calling them respectively where needed. the reason was I thought it didn't matter that they were on the same variable since they were in different functions. after reading around and getting some answers I realized how silly that is.

Here's my code. 
HTML:

```
<section class="header">
<div class="searchSync">
    <form>
        <button type="submit" class="searchButton " ng-click='getPokes(); getMorePokes()'>
        <img class="PokeCon" src ="../Fonts/PokeBall.png"></button>
        <input type="text" class="searchBar" ng-model="pokeName " placeholder="Search your Pokedex!">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="pokeTitle pokeFont">
    PokeDev
</div>


<section class="pokedexScreen">

    <div class="pokeDisplay">
        <div class="pokeProfilePic">
            <img class="Profile" ng-src='{{pokeData.sprites.front_default}}'>
            <h3 class='pokeName'>{{pokeData.name.toUpperCase()}}</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="pokeDescription">
            <p class='pokeHeight'>Meters:{{pokeData.height}}</p>
            <h6 class='pokeWeight'>Weight:{{pokeData.weight}}</h6>


        </div>
        <div class="otherPokeInfo">
            <p class='pokedexNumber'>#{{pokeData.id}}</p>
            <h3 class='pokeFlavorText'>{{pokeData.flavor_text_entries[53].flavor_text}}</h3>


        </div>
</section>
<section class="pokedexScreen"
```

Controller:

```
// INITILIZE CONTROLLER
// ============================================================
angular.module("app").controller("pokeCtrl", function($scope, pokeService) {

// VARIABLES
// ============================================================


// FUNCTIONS
// ============================================================
$scope.getPokes = function() {
    pokeService.getPokes($scope.pokeName.toLowerCase())
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(pokeService, response);
            $scope.pokeData = response;
        })
}

//=====================================================================

$scope.getMorePokes = function() {
    pokeService.getMorePokes($scope.pokeName.toLowerCase())
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(pokeService, response);
            $scope.pokeData = response;
        })
}

});
```

Service:

```
// INITILIZE SERVICE
// ============================================================
angular.module("app").service("pokeService", function($http) {

// CRUD FUNCTIONS
// ============================================================
this.getMorePokes = function(pokeName) {
    return $http({
        url: 'http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/' + pokeName,
        method: 'GET'
    }).then(function(response) {
        console.log('service:', response);
        return response.data;

    })
}
this.getPokes = function(pokeName) {
    return $http({
        url: 'http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + pokeName,
        method: 'GET'
    }).then(function(response) {
        // console.log('service:', response);
        return response.data;

    })
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You assigned the result to `pokeData` in both `getPokes` and `getMorePokes`

```
$scope.pokeData = response;
```

So whatever returned first from the API will be overwritten by whatever returned second.

In your template it seems you are only displaying one Pokemon. You need to work on it a bit to display more. For example, you can use `ngRepeat` (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

Comment: Thank you so much Daniel! been stuck staring at my code for so long :)  I had originally planned on using a ng-repeat for the pokedex , but looking at the documentation it seems I can only pull one name/id at a time so I went for the one Pokemon on the page template.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are assigning to `$scope.pokeData` from both of your functions which is letting it down after a moment or two.

```
$scope.getMorePokes = function() {
    pokeService.getMorePokes($scope.pokeName.toLowerCase())
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.pokeData = response;     <== This is the issue in my view, more pokes should be set in some sort of an array, its currently overwriting the previous pokeData
        })
}
```

Also, its great to see you have much simplified approach now in your service.

Comment: Hey thanks Ali! a lot less lines of code for sure! I had a previous project I looked back at and facepalmed over how over complex I was making things!

Comment: Yeah! That was terrifying ;)